# How to hide an existing field in an OpenERP7 view?

Tags: forms, python-2.7, view, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to hide a field called `street2` in an existing OpenERP7 view only if a field called `is_company` values `True`. I have to do this using inheritance, so I created a new view with a form called `res.partner.extended.form`, which inherits from the view I want to modify (`base.view_partner_form`).

To make `street2` invisible, I left my inherited form this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="res_partner_extended_view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.extended.form</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="/form//field[@name='street2']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

But this way, I make the field invisible, with any condition. I need to make it invisible only if `is_company` values `True`. So I tried several ways, and I am not able to manage it. The next lines are one of my failed attempts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="res_partner_extended_view">
            <field name="name">res.partner.extended.form</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="/form//field[@name='street2']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">[('is_company', '=', 'True')]</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Anyone knows how to manage this? Am I close to the answer? Any help will be appreciated a lot. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="res_partner_extended_view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.extended.form</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form" />
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name='street2' position="attributes">
                <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible': [('is_company', '=', True)]}</attribute>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
</data>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!! I tried in other attempt with "attrs", but I did not know that I had to put the content between {}. Thank you!!

Comment: you can use direct field tag like `field` or give full path of field like in `xpath expr='full path'`