# How to hide a field programmatically in Odoo?

Tags: python, field, hide, odoo

I am trying to make a module for Odoo and I don't know how to hide a field using python code
This line doesn't work for me :

```
'form_id': fields.many2one('dev.test', 'candidat', select=False,invisible=True),
```

I want to hide it using python and not using xml because I didn't declare that many2one field in my xml it's just a simple field in my test relation, the field will be created inside the popup to create new "formation".

This is the definition of the field that make the relationship

```
    'test_form_ids': fields.one2many('dev.form', 'form_id','formations'),
```

[test_form_ids one2many field capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh6Ws.png)

This is my formation class

```
class dev_form(osv.Model):
_name='dev.form'
_description='rel between test & formations'

_columns = {
    'name': fields.many2one('dev.name', 'Formation'),
  'form_id': fields.many2one('dev.test', 'candidat', select=False,invisible=True),
}
```

highlighted the field I want to hide here 
[the popup to create new formation capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhF2D.png)

Comment: If you want to hide any field than it's simple to not write in .xml file as in your case. Following link will be help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553169/selectively-display-or-hide-button-in-the-tree-view-in-openerp/27553392#27553392 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054744/how-to-hide-an-existing-field-in-an-openerp7-view/26055542#26055542

Comment: I didn't understand your solution because I can't see any python code in it... I tried using atrrs in python it doesn't work too 

'cand_lan_id': fields.many2one('dev.test', 'test', select=False,attrs="{'invisible':True}"'),'

can you please explain

Comment: If you want to hide field by programmatic than we need to override method. In which condition you want to hide that field ?

Comment: I want to remove it from the users view without any conditions,
it seems a bit silly but I can't find a better solution
I just need that field to make the one2many relationship ,sorry, am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: there is no xml, it's a field inside a relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open your view *.xml* file where *cand_lan_id* you declared.

Now replace field

```
<field name="cand_lan_id"/>
```

with

```
<field name="cand_lan_id" invisible="1"/>
```

*invisible="1"* is attribute which will hide your field from the User.

EDIT:

Open .xml file in which *test_form_ids* field is declare.

Now replace field

```
<field name="test_form_ids"/>
```

with

```
<field name="test_form_ids">
    <form string="Form Name">
        <field name="name"/>
        <field name="form_id" invisible="1"/>
        <!-- List of field that User want to see in form view -->
    </form>
    <tree string="Form Name" editable="bottom">
        <field name="name"/>
        <!-- List of field that User want to see as a columns -->
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: I understand your solution & thank you so much for help 
but I need to do it in python coz I don't have any xml 
the field I am dealing with is declared inside a relationship that will be created automatically when you create new product

Comment: If you don't declared in .xml file than no worry about the hiding field. Field in only visible if we declare in .xml file. Now in your case, You didn't declare in .xml file means field is not visible to End User.

Comment: it's visible in my case.
one2many relation give me the option to create new products & all included fields in the relation collums will be visible in creation automatically.

Comment: you can see images in my question now